# The easiest way to store session value

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, local-storage, session-cookies

Sorry for being very stupid, but I really can't get my head around it. There are many different options  like Cookies, LocalStorage, LocalForage, Session Cookies, etc.

What I need though is to store user information, and I have to do it on the server (I'm using node and express), I mean I can determine user on the server, and I have to send it to the client, and store it in browser's session store.

And I can't use just regular cookies, I don't want to persist that between the sessions.

with the cookie I could just do:

```
apt.get '/', (req, res)->
   res.cookie 'user', currentUser
```

But doing similar thing with `res.session` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Update after discussion**.

Sounds like you should look at the basic approach of:

- Take the user data you have on the server but want available in the browser, serialize it to JSON on the server
- transfer that user JSON data to the browser in an HTML `<script>` tag whenever there's a full page load. Something like `<script>window.USER = {"name": "Agzam"};</script>`
- when your JS on the page starts to run, you have access to it directly: `window.USER`

You can just leave it there in memory and it will go away when the window/tab is closed.

I recommend [sharify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sharify) as a secure and convenient way to do this. It integrates with express and browserify. If you don't use sharify, be aware that the rules for properly encoding JSON inside HTML are tricky.

> I don't want to persist that between the sessions

Don't use `localStorage` or anything backed by `localStorage` then as they will persist longer.

Comment: no, no I don't care about making it secure, my api calls are secure (that we care about). I need user-info just to display username on the screen, in different places, for that I need to store it somehow (on the client)